# django filter to calculate hours within range

Tags: python, django

I have a set of data that effectively defines a datetime stamp "in" and datetime stamp "out" for when someone was working.   Each person will have multiple combinations of in-s and out-s over many months.

```
class InOut(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    in_dt = models.DateTime
    out_dt = models.DateTime
    hours = models.FloatField
```

(then I actually currently have a signal which calculates the hours worked between out_dt and in_dt.)

I want to write code/filter/query that calculates the total hours they worked between start_date and end_date (e.g., over a month).  The kicker is if they started work on the last day of a month and then ended on the first of the next month the hours should only include the hours up to midnight of the last day of the month.

Now, I can create a queryset that filters for all entries which are contained between start_date and end_date (e.g., the month).

```
worked_in_month = InOut.objects.filter( in_dt__lte=end_date, out_dt__gte=start_date)
```

and then I can do an annotation or values and annotation and Sum(hours) but that doesn't account for hours outside of start_date/end_date.  OR I can try and do something with the in_dt and out_dt and ignore the precalculated hours.

I can obviously do the calculations in python (which might be the only answer) but was wondering if I might be missing something in Djano with filtering etc.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, I'd probably insert an extra start/end entry at the end-of-month wraparound just to simplify further processing.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are thinking but would like to hear more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of at least two approaches to your problem.

**A (rather convoluted) query:**

```
month_start = datetime(year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, tz);
next_month = (month % 12) + 1
next_month_start = datetime(year, next_month, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, tz)

models.InOut.objects.filter(
    (
        Q(in_dt__gte=month_start) and Q(in_dt__lt=next_month_start))
        | (Q(out_dt__gte=month_start) and Q(out_dt__lt=next_month_start)
    )
 ).annotate(
     start_in_month=Func(F('in_dt'), month_start, function='MAX'),
     end_in_month=Func(F('out_dt'), month_end, function='MIN')
 ).aggregate(worked=Sum(F('end_in_month') - F('start_in_month'))
```

If using PostgreSQL you need to use

```
 .annotate(
     start_in_month=Func(F('in_dt'), month_start, function='GREATEST'),
     end_in_month=Func(F('out_dt'), month_end, function='LEAST')
 )
```

since in PostgreSQL `MAX()` and `MIN()` are not defined for date types.

Note also the aggregation does not work on SQLite because it does not have the appropriate data types (dates are stored as text).

**Preprocessing entries**

In your database, the `InOut` entries that span the month border are logically (not physically) two entries:

1. One that starts at the designated time and ends at the month end
2. One that starts at the end of the month and ends at the designated time

Filtering out the affected `InOut` objects takes a little thinking, especially since `F()` objects cannot (currently) resolve parts of datetimes (e.g. `in_dt__month`).

Something one the lines of

```
# XXX - magic number of months
for month in range(1, 13):
    for wraparound in models.InOut.objects.filter(
        Q(in_dt__month=month) and ~Q(out_dt__month=month)
    )
        year = wraparound.in_dt.year
        next_month = (month % 12) + 1
        month_end = datetime(year, next_month, calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1], 23, 59, 59, 999999, tz)
        next_month_start = datetime(year, next_month, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, tz)

        models.InOut.objects.bulk_create([
            models.InOut(user=wraparound.user, in_dt=wraparound.in_dt, out_dt=month_end),
            models.InOut(user=wraparound.user, in_dt=next_month_start, out_dt=wraparound.out_dt)
        ])
        wraparound.delete()
```

could do the trick, however.

Ideally, you don't do this afterwards but already when saving the time entry in your view. However this might confound users because they now get two entries instead of one when entering a wraparound work span.

**Caveat emptor**: You might need to dicker around with `next_month`, `next_month_start` and `__lt` as well as `__gte` a bit, because this 
implementation looses a microsecond at the end of each wraparound after expansion.

And yes, it is a nice exercise ;-)

Comment: Ah, thank you! I had not seen the Func/Max/Min parts. That looks like it will work and will be more efficient.  I'll give it a try...

Comment: I am using postgres and it seems there needs to be some casting that might have to happen as it doesn't like max with datetime instances.  If you know a way around, that would be great, otherwise I'll try and figure it out and post.

Comment: Hmm, it seems for PostgreSQL you must use [`GREATEST()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) and `LEAST()` for date types. This looses database portability, since these aren't pure SQL functions any more.

Comment: Ah, perfect.  I added a values in there as well.

Comment: Went away from this for a bit and had to come back to this.  I am close but I can't seem to do the last part. Your last line aggregate sum works but what I really want is to do it per user (shortened some things for clarity): `.annotate(sim=F('in_dt'),eim=F('out_dt'),worked=(F('out_dt')-F('in_dt'))).values('user').annotate(t=Sum(F('worked')))` but the final annotate gives me an error "KeyError: 'worked'".  I am close but it seems the worked isn't getting pushed through the values (??).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer above, here is what I have (not verified but appears to work):

```
ins = InOut.objects.filter(
    (
       Q(in_dt__gte=start_date) and Q(in_dt__lt=end_date)) |
        (Q(out_dt__gte=start_date) and Q(out_dt__lt=end_date)
    )
).values('user').annotate(
   start_in_month=Func(F('in_dt'), start_date, function='greatest'),
   end_in_month=Func(F('out_dt'), end_date, function='least')
).annotate(worked=Sum(F('end_in_month') - F('start_in_month')))
```

Thanks so much @dhke, very helpful.